# phpmyadmin order by (likes done within x time-dislikes done within x time)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a sql command which can order rows by (likes minus dislikes) which have been done within a timeframe. The example below shows how I did this when I only had likes(it works), but when taking dislikes into account it became to complicated for me.

```
SELECT count(likes.lid) as 'amount', posts.* FROM likes 
join posts on posts.pid = likes.pid
WHERE likes.DateLiked >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -3 DAY)
group by likes.pid order by amount  DESC;
```

I currently have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    pid int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    uid int(11) not null,
    Content text not null,
    Category varchar(100) not null,
    Subject varchar(100) not null,
    DatePublished datetime not null,
    TypeData VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
    Data VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE likes (
    lid int(12) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    uid int(11) NOT NULL,
    Username varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    pid int(11) NOT NULL,
    DateLiked DateTime NOT NULL,
    ipConnect varchar(200) NOT NULL

)

CREATE TABLE dislikes (
    lid int(12) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    uid int(11) NOT NULL,
    Username varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    pid int(11) NOT NULL,
    DateLiked DateTime NOT NULL,
    ipConnect varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm looking for a command which can order posts by highest rating(likes-dislikes) within a certain timeframe(i.e. if someone liked 2 days ago it counts but one year ago doesn't count).

Any and all help is appreciated,
have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate first, then join:

```
select
  coalesce(l.cnt, 0) - coalesce(dl.cnt, 0) as likes,
  p.*
from posts p
left join
(
  select pid, count(*) as cnt
  from likes
  where dateliked >= date_add(current_date, interval -3 day)
  group by pid
) l on l.pid = p.pid
left join
(
  select pid, count(*) as cnt
  from dislikes
  where dateliked >= date_add(current_date, interval -3 day)
  group by pid
) dl on dl.pid = p.pid
order by coalesce(l.cnt, 0) - coalesce(dl.cnt, 0) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I might be doing something wrong since this kind of mysql is beyond me, but I can't get it to work. I have a bunch of demo posts with a varying amount of dislikes/likes, but the "likes" column is zero for each row except the first and last, which have +1234 and -984 respectively. The one with -984 likes also has the most UpVotes, apart from that the order seems random. I can't find a way to upload the exact values here, I'm new. If you have the time, could you look over your code? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot the `GROUP BY` clauses, so rather than get a count per pid I got a total count with a random pid. Another DBMS would have raised an error. (And I think newer MySQL versions do so too). I've updated my answer.